# how to read a value from a function in PyQt

Tags: python

This code is for using the checkbox in PyQt. TE1 allows me to read the state of the checkbox.

```
self.RS422_TE1.stateChanged.connect(self.Check_RS422TE1)

def Check_RS422TE1(self,TE1):
    if TE1 == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        Enable_TE1 = 1 
    else:
        Enable_TE1 = 0
        #print Enable_TE1
    return Enable_TE1
```

I would like using the return command,read the value of the function `Enable_TE1 Check_RS422TE1`. How could I do ?

Comment: What you wrote doesn't make sense. You can't `read the value of the function Enable_TE1` because that's not a function, it's a variable.

Comment: Why you call `Enable_TE1` a function, I see it in your code as a variable?..Can you explain more?

Comment: Wayne Werner the post has been published in error.It is shown by the code that I entered what is variable and what is the function. Function Check_RS422TE1 should I read the value of the variable Enable_TE1. How can I make taking into account the code I posted? Thanks for the possible answer

Comment: Iron Fist the post has been published in error.It is shown by the code that I entered what is variable and what is the function. Function Check_RS422TE1 should I read the value of the variable Enable_TE1. How can I make taking into account the code I posted? Thanks for the possible answer

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two possible options. Using the `stateChanged` signal Qt will invoke your callback `Check_RS422TE1` when the widget is checked or unchecked; just make your stuff inside that function, there's no need to return anything. Or, just use `self.RS422_TE1.isChecked()` anywhere inside your class to make your logic.

Comment: The first option I already implemented in the code I posted. I will try to implement the second option. Thank you